# Unsubscribe matching email address in all subscribers using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, unsubscribe

Hi I'm new in ampscript and I have a requirement to unsubscribe all matching email address in all subscribers once they click the unsubscribe button. Is this possible using Ampscript?

Thank you!

Comment: This question is a simple yes and no question. Please read. [How to ask questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I think, based on your question, that you may have duplicate subscribers and wish to unsubscribe all matching email addresses (across different subscriber keys)?

If so, when an unsubscribe takes place for a subscriber, you're able to also unsubscribe any other subscriber keys that share the same email address using a four-step automation:

1. SQL query returning Subscriber Keys where the associated email address has at least one unsubscribed record in the All Subscribers list and one that is not unsubscribed.

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT
   s1.emailaddress, 
   s2.subscriberkey,
   'unsubscribed' status,
   s1.DateUnsubscribed [DateUnsubscribed]
   from _subscribers s1
   inner join _subscribers s2 on (s2.emailaddress = s1.emailaddress and 
   s2.status != 'unsubscribed')
   where s1.status = 'unsubscribed'
   ```
2. Data Extract activity, to extract a .csv file of the Data Extension populated in the previous step (which will need SubscriberKey, EmailAddress, DateUnsubscribed and Status as fields). The Status value is actually what you'll be updating it to, so I have this labelled in my DE as Status_to_update_to to avoid any confusion.
3. File transfer activity, to transfer the file from the previous step to the Import folder on the Marketing Cloud SFTP, where it can be processed from.
4. Import activity, to import the file into the All Subscribers list to unsubscribe the records from the file.